# Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Error: Handshake failed: no matching key exchange algorithm

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, serviceconnection

I have a SSH service connection in Azure DevOps using username and password. It was working till last/before week. Azure DevOps cant connect to VM any more, there has been no changes. I can still connect to VM using Putty of ssh.

pipeline task instantly fails with below error:

```
Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Error: Handshake failed: no matching key exchange algorithm.
```

Comment: What tasks and agents are you using? [Copy files over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops) or others? MS hosted agent or self-hosted agent you are using? What about removing the existing SSH service connection and create a new one? Does it have the same issue?

Comment: I am using SSH deployment task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops) to run commands on remote server.

Source host is windows ( self hosted), from where Azure DevOps uses SSH  task with SSH service connection.

I have removed, created new, changed user password, none of these has helped.

Only thing I could think of, its centos5, MS has been removing some weak chipper and might be old algorithm which centos5 uses.

Comment: Any solution @Shankar?

Comment: Didn’t find any solution yet. We are looking to upgrade os version.